# Dynamsoft Android SDK clashes with okhttp3

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, okhttp

I am working in a company project and there is a requirement to integrate **Dynamsoft Android SDK** for document scanning purpose. This problem is, when the sdk dependency is added to the current project, it get clashes with **okhttp3** while giving this error on Build-console :

**Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>     Program type already present: okhttp3.Address
>     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.**

As it suggests in Developer console, okhttp3 has been excluded(actually tried in manifold ways) from Dynamsoft dependency yet problem remains.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "no.aspit.capture"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

        dev {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug {

        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz'
    }
}


kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.4.0'

    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.6.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'


    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //Joda time
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'
    // Image Compression
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    //Stetho
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

    //Dynumsoft
    implementation ('com.dynamsoft:dynamsoftcamerasdk:2.0@aar'){
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
    }


}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://download.dynamsoft.com/maven/dcs"
    }
```

Comment: package is not `com.squareup.okhttp3` so `exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'` excludes nothing

Comment: I suppose another package - implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0' also includes okhttp3

Comment: @Ajantha1311 have you got the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve the conflicts as follows:

```
configurations.all {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio', module: 'okio'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.4.0'

    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.6.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'


    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //Joda time
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'
    // Image Compression
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    //Stetho
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

    //Dynumsoft
    implementation ('com.dynamsoft:dynamsoftcamerasdk:2.0@aar')
}
```